Interpreting Indirect Lagged Treatment Effects When Simulating Panel Data
Consider the following DAG where I am interested in estimating the current (X2) and lagged (X1) treatment effect on Y2:

Next, consider the following data generating process implied by the DAG:
library(dplyr)

set.seed(12345)
n <- 2000

dgp2_wide <- tibble(id = 1:n) %>% 
  # Create Lagged and Current Treatment and Outcome Values
  mutate(Z1 = rnorm(n, 0, 1),
         X1 = (0.1 * Z1) + rnorm(n, 0, sqrt(0.99)),
         Y1 = (0.1 * Z1) + (0.4 * X1) + rnorm(n, 0, sqrt(0.822)),
         Z2 = (0.2 * Z1) + (0.4 * X1) + rnorm(n, 0, 1),
         X2 = (0.1 * Z2) + (0.4 * X1) + rnorm(n, 0, sqrt(0.5196)),
         # Indirect Effect of X1 on Y2 is ?
         Y2 = (0.2 * Z2) + (0.4 * X2) + (0.4 * Y1) + rnorm(n, 0, sqrt(0.4582)))

How would I determine what the indirect effect of X1 -> Y2? X1 causes some change in Z2 which causes some change in Y2. How can I determine what impact X1 has on Y2, filtered through Z2?
Note, I am not asking for a method to estimate this (I am learning about marginal structural models now). I want to know how I can determine what the lagged indirect effect is given the information I am simulating.

Are all the variables observed? Or are there hidden variables?

Let's solve this step by step by tracing the indirect path from X1 to Y2 through Z2.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
To find the indirect effect of X1 on Y2 through Z2, we need to:

First identify the coefficient for X1 → Z2: 0.4
Then identify the coefficient for Z2 → Y2: 0.2
Multiply these coefficients: 0.4 * 0.2 = 0.08

However, there's also another indirect path through Z2:
X1 → Z2 → X2 → Y2
Let's trace this:

X1 → Z2: 0.4
Z2 → X2: 0.1
X2 → Y2: 0.4
Multiply: 0.4 * 0.1 * 0.4 = 0.016

Therefore, the total indirect effect through Z2 is:

Through Z2 directly: 0.08
Through Z2 → X2: 0.016
Total: 0.096

Note that this is only the portion of the indirect effect that goes through Z2. There are other indirect paths (notably through Y1) that would need to be included for the total indirect effect of X1 on Y2.

So if I wanted to understand the total effect of X1 on Y2, I would also have to account for the X1 -> Y1 -> Y2 path? So if the effect for X1 -> Z2 -> Y2 is 0.08, and the effect for X1 -> Z2 -> X2 -> Y2 is 0.016, and the effect for X1 -> Y1 -> Y2 is (I think) 0.16, then the total effect of X1 on Y2 would be 0.256 (0.08 + 0.016 + 0.16)?

@BrianLookabaugh Yes, that's correct! The total effect of X1 on Y2 is indeed the sum of all indirect paths: 1) X1 → Z2 → Y2: 0.4 * 0.2 = 0.08 2) X1 → Z2 → X2 → Y2: 0.4 * 0.1 * 0.4 = 0.016
3) X1 → Y1 → Y2: 0.4 * 0.4 = 0.16. Your calculation of 0.256 as the total effect is correct. This represents all the ways that X1 influences Y2 through the various pathways in your DAG. The path through Y1 (0.16) actually turns out to be the strongest indirect effect, which makes intuitive sense given that it's a more direct pathway compared to the paths that go through Z2.
